# Rails find_by_sql and parameter for id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Qucik question, why is the 2nd line of code working and the first not?

```
Detail.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM details INNER JOIN players ON players.id = details.player_id WHERE players.team_id = ?", self.id)
Detail.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM details INNER JOIN players ON players.id = details.player_id WHERE players.team_id = '#{self.id}'")
```

first line gives me MySQL error, looks like it doesn't pass the parameter to the SQL

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1: SELECT * FROM details INNER JOIN players ON players.id = details.player_id WHERE players.team_id = ?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use it like this :

```
Detail.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM details INNER JOIN players ON players.id = details.player_id WHERE players.team_id = ?", self.id])
```

Comment: The only drawback here is that you can't do scope chaining with `find_by_sql`.

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to comment on AshwinKumarS's answer, but seems I have no rep points, so I have to post here. He gave the right answer, but with no explanation. Yes, `find_by_sql` only accepts **a single array** as its parameter. If you look at [the API doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql), it gives a **wrong** method signature (showing the `sql` parameter as independent of the bind array, but the samples below it are correct). I just wasted, like, an hour, trying to debug a problem caused by this (and of course it shows up as a MySQL syntax error rather than a Rails error - very confusing and frustrating!) Because this method only accepts a single, flat array, if you have many, or a variable number of parameters to pass, do it like this:

```
Detail.find_by_sql(["SELECT * FROM blah WHERE column1 = ? AND column2 in (?,?,?)", array_of_values].flatten)
```

Comment: You can also write `[sql, *binds]` instead of `.flatten`.

Answer (score -1):

find_by_sql supports only sql queries while you are using rails syntax

You should write your query in sql syntax like this:

```
Detail.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM details INNER JOIN players ON players.id = details.player_id WHERE players.team_id = #{self.id}")
```

**Or,** you can also find it in rails syntax:

```
Detail.joins(:player).where("players.team_id = ?", self.id)
```

Comment: I don't think using string concat is an acceptable solution to the problem

Comment: And besides that the answer is outright wrong in saying that what the OP wants to do is not supported